# The Sopranos - Final Episode: Where is the proof that "Man In Members Only Jacket" is in fact credited by that name?

Tags: the-sopranos

I can't find any video of the final episode of *The Sopranos* in which the character played by Paolo Colandrea is credited as "Man In Members Only Jacket" in the closing credits after the blackout, as alleged in many blogs and forums.

All videos I can find end with these credits:

[image]

I suppose that there are more credits until the HBO logo but I can't find any "proof" of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are more credits after that point.  Here's a screen capture from the DVD release:

[image: Sopranos End Credits]

As you can see, Paolo Colandrea is credited as "Man in Members Only Jacket" at 59:28.